# How to access Kafka headers while consuming a message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

Below are my configuration

```
<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter"
            kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
            auto-startup="true"
            channel="inputFromKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" />
    </int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

`inputFromKafka` goes through transformation below

```
public Message<?> transform(final Message<?> message) {

System.out.println( "KAFKA Message Headers " + message.getHeaders());

final Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>> origData =  (Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>) message.getPayload();

        // some code to figure-out the nonPartitionedData
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(nonPartitionedData).build();
    }
```

The print statement from above  prints only two consistent headers regardless

`KAFKA Message Headers {id=9c8f09e6-4b28-5aa1-c74c-ebfa53c01ae4, timestamp=1437066957272}`

While Sending a Kafka message some headers were passed including `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` but I am not getting back that either, wondering if there is away to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work that way...

The `Producer` part (`KafkaProducerMessageHandler`) looks like this:

```
this.kafkaProducerContext.send(topic, partitionId, messageKey, message.getPayload());
```

As you see we don't send any `messageHeaders` to the Kafka `topic`. Only `payload` and exactly under that `messageKey` as it specified by Kafka protocol.

From other side the `Consumer` side (`KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSource`) does this logic:

```
if (!payloadMap.containsKey(messageAndMetadata.partition())) {
    final List<Object> payload = new ArrayList<Object>();
    payload.add(messageAndMetadata.message());
    payloadMap.put(messageAndMetadata.partition(), payload);
}
```

As you see we don't care here about `messageKey`.

The `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` (`<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter>`) is for you! It does this before sending the message to the channel:

```
KafkaMessageHeaders kafkaMessageHeaders = new KafkaMessageHeaders(generateMessageId, generateTimestamp);

Map<String, Object> rawHeaders = kafkaMessageHeaders.getRawHeaders();
rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, key);
rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, metadata.getPartition().getTopic());
rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, metadata.getPartition().getId());
rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, metadata.getOffset());
rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.NEXT_OFFSET, metadata.getNextOffset());

if (!this.autoCommitOffset) {
    rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, acknowledgment);
}
```

Comment: `...some headers were passed including...` Kafka has no concept of headers; if you want to transfer custom information, it has to be in the payload.

Comment: Where exactly it sets those headers?
I cannot find that here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/inbound/KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java

Comment: Since there too match has been changed. Please, meet Spring Kafka 2.1 already: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/ !

Answer (score 0):

As stated before there's no concept of message headers in Kafka. Because I struggled with that same problem in the past I've compiled a [small library](https://github.com/leandronunes85/messaging) that helps tackle this issue. It may come handy to you.